# Проблема компиляции исходных файлов через CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

компилятор при попытке скомпилировать выдает ошибку(не судите строго я пока мало в этом разбираюсь):

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (add_executable):
Cannot find source file:

```
src/main.cpp
```

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
.hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (add_executable):
No SOURCES given to target: MyProject

[image]
Пожалуйста скажите что можно сделать, заранее спасибо.

[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Файла `src/main.cpp` (относительно расположения `CMakeLists.txt`) не существует. Все пути в `CMakeLists.txt` относительны.

Один из вариантов исправить -- переместить `CMakeLists.txt` в корень проекта.

Comment: А, как тогда надо?

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: Если не сложно можете скинуть как будет выглядеть команда компиляции CMakeLists.txt если он в корне проекта

Answer (score 0):

Первым аргументом cmake обычно идет указание где находится CMakeLists.txt, далее ключ -S в cmake указывает где находятся исходные файлы проекта, -B где находится каталог сборки, если вы все же не хотите менять структуру, можете попробовать использовать из корневой директории проекта `cmake build/ -Ssrc -Bbuild/CMake`.